# How to make python recognize Uppercase and Lower case for input WHILE using elif

Tags: python, python-3.x

So i am a beginner in Python, actually in programming in general.
I wanna ask how to recognize upper and lower case input while using elif,
this question probably been asked many times but, while the solution that
i've seen online did help it didn't match my problem.

This actually kinda work, when i type "Min" or "min" it does work and prints out the result. However, when i run it and type "tzu", either lower case or upper case
it prints out "WRONG". So it didn't match what the outcome should be.

Here is my code take a look. Even though it's not for school or homework,
just me bored doing it for fun, please help it would mean A LOT. i've been dying trying to figure this out since yesterday.

```
tw1 = ["Min".lower(), "Tzu".lower(), "Mo".lower()]
tw2 = "Nay".lower()
tw1.append(tw2.lower())

print(tw1)
word = input("which one is part of the school meal club?\n")
if tw1[0].lower() in tw1:
    print("WRONG")
elif tw1[1].lower() in tw1:
    print("CORRECT YES!")
elif tw1[2].lower() in tw1:
    print("WRONG")
```

Comment: Why do you input the `word` variable and don't use it anywhere else?

Comment: It will ***always*** be `"WRONG"` because you're checking `if tw1[0].lower() in tw1`. But that will always be true... You're checking if an item from `tw1` is in `tw1`... Did you mean to do `if word in tw1`? (No need for `elif/else`)

Comment: When copying code, indentation might break. It is recommended that you check the outcome, and edit it if it needs it !
You cant use Tab in this editor, so just put 4 spaces instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

```py
tw1 = ["Min".lower(), "Tzu".lower(), "Mo".lower()]
tw2 = "Nay".lower()
tw1.append(tw2.lower())

print(tw1)
word = input("which one is part of the school meal club?\n")

if word.lower() in tw1:
    print("correct")
else:
    print("wrong")
```

Comment: Oh it did help, just had to add [0] next to if word.lower() in tw1: so it's like this if word.lower() in tw1[0]:
Really thank you so much tho! this never crossed my mind in the first place, cheers.